# jQuery / css addClass() style overriding previous style property

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, addclass

I have a div with its default class giving it a green background. When the mouse is pressed, I want to change the background to red until the mouse is let go.

I have tried to addClass a class with a red background-color. The new class properties seem to not override the existing properties. I have the new class listed after the original in the .css file.

css

```
#calc_no { background-color: #cd9781; }
#calc_yes { background-color: #8fba8e; }
.button_click { background-color: red; }
```

jscript

```
$('.button').live('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).addClass("button_click");
});
$('.button').live('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('button_click');
});
```

html

```
<div id="calc_yes" class="kp_button button">Yes</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that ids override class definitions.  change the background in classes instead of ids

Comment: thank aletzo too, he got it first (while i was writing mine).  upvotes are a nice way to say thinks in Stack Overflow. Good luck coding, sailor!

Answer (score 4):

In CSS, different types of selectors have different weights. An id has greater weight than a class, which has greater weight than a tag name, for example. So, your id-based styles are overriding the class-based styles.

For this simple case, try using the `!important` keyword:

```
.button_click { background-color: red !important; }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: that id a correct answer, but using `!important` should be a last-resort solution, since it breaks the cascading rules and causes problems maintining the code later.

Answer (score 1):

ids > classes

you could use .calc_no and .calc_yes instead